# Create jQuery Validate rule for positive whole numbers

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How do I create a rule for only positive whole numbers greater then 0 (ex. 1,2,3,4,5,etc)?

```js
var form = $('#formClientLicense')[0];
$(form).validate();

var quantity = $(form).find("input[name='Quantity']")[0];
$(quantity).rules("add", {
    required: true,
    min: 1,
    step: 1,
    number: true,
    messages: {
        required: jQuery.validator.format("Required Field"),
        number: "Not a number",
        min: jQuery.validator.format("Please select positive number"),
        step: jQuery.validator.format("Please select whole number (ex. 1,2,3,4)")
    }
});

if ($(form).valid()) {
    // run here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For a postive whole number greater than zero, combine the `min` rule with the `integer` rule.  The `integer` rule can be found within [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js).

```
$(quantity).rules("add", {
    required: true,
    min: 1,
    integer: true,
    messages: {
        required: jQuery.validator.format("Required Field"),
        min: jQuery.validator.format("Please select positive number"),
        integer: jQuery.validator.format("Please select whole number (ex. 1,2,3,4)")  
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/h6bsawqb/](http://jsfiddle.net/h6bsawqb/)**

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is

```
    $( "#myform" ).validate({
      rules: {
        field: {
          required: true,
          digits: true
        }
      }
    });
```

Ref : digits method | jQuery Validation Plugin --> https://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `min` and `step` for that.

This way, it will only accept a multiple of 1, starting at 1.

```
$(quantity).rules("add", {
        number: true
        min: 1,
        step: 1,
        messages: {
            number: "Not a number",
            min: jQuery.validator.format("Please select positive number"),
            step: "Enter a integer number."
        }
});
```

You don't need `minlenght`, as that is for strings.

Comment: It doesn't seem like step works. When I run form.valid() I get an error that says "jquery.validate.js:563 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

Comment: Note that the `step` method is a fairly recent addition so you'll need the latest version.